# React native reanimated

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

I am trying to create a toggle player animation in react native, the same like Spotify, where when you press the `miniPlayer` , the full size player will show, my problem is that the fullSize Player View is `transparent`, and I can't seem to get the background of that view to render the proper `color`.

I created a snack since the original Project is huge and to better understand the issue:
https://snack.expo.io/@git/github.com/oflarcade/MPlayer

> MiniPlayer

[image: MINI PLAYER]

> Full Size Player

[image: FULL SIZE PLAYER]